# Android Nougat data binding npe on rotate

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-7.0-nougat

I have the issue with data binding layout.
On Nougat and up when rotate the device the data binding throws the following exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.package/com.package.mobile.ui.activity.property.ForSaleActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
com.package.mobile.databinding.ViewPropertyResultsGridBinding.invalidateAll()'
on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5382)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:221)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) Caused
by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'void
com.package.mobile.databinding.ViewPropertyResultsGridBinding.invalidateAll()'
on a null object reference
       at com.package.mobile.databinding.FragmentPropertyResultsBinding.invalidateAll(FragmentPropertyResultsBinding.java:76)
       at com.package.mobile.databinding.FragmentPropertyResultsBinding.<init>(FragmentPropertyResultsBinding.java:67)
       at com.package.mobile.databinding.FragmentPropertyResultsBinding.bind(FragmentPropertyResultsBinding.java:329)
       at android.databinding.DataBinderMapper.getDataBinder(DataBinderMapper.java:307)
       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:185)
       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:120)
       at com.package.mobile.databinding.FragmentPropertyResultsBinding.inflate(FragmentPropertyResultsBinding.java:314)
       at com.package.mobile.databinding.FragmentPropertyResultsBinding.inflate(FragmentPropertyResultsBinding.java:311)
       at com.package.mobile.ui.fragment.property.PropertyResultsFragment.createBinding(PropertyResultsFragment.java:214)
       at com.package.mobile.ui.fragment.property.PropertyResultsFragment.createBinding(PropertyResultsFragment.java:114)
       at com.package.mobile.ui.fragment.DataBindingFragment.onCreateView(DataBindingFragment.java:27)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2900)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:603)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
       at com.package.mobile.ui.activity.base.AppCompatRoboActivity.onStart(AppCompatRoboActivity.java:70)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265)
       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3216)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5382)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:221)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I have results fragment where the binding is created using the way:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup  container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   mBinding = createBinding(inflater, container);

     return mBinding.getRoot();
```

Seems that for some reason the binding object is not created at all when the device is rotated.

The content of the createBinding method is:

```
 @Override
    protected FragmentPropertyResultsBinding createBinding(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container) {
        return FragmentPropertyResultsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: The problem was that i had declared some layouts as merges instead of declaring them as <layout>.. <data><data></layout>.

Comment: If you have found an answer, please post it & mark it as correct as it may help other users in the future